# SAS group rows based on time intervals

Tags: sas

I am doing some analysis on a dataset with a variable named "time". The time is in the format of HH:MM:SS.

However, now I want to group the rows based on 5 secs and 1 min time intervals respectively in two different analysis.

I checked some StackOverflow posts online, but it seems that they used a variable called "Interval" which starts at 1 and increases when the interval ends.

```
data _quotes_interval; 
  set _quotes_processed;
  interval = intck('MINUTE1',"09:30:00"t,time)+1;
run;
```

What I want to do is to keep the time format. For example, if the original time is 9:00:30, and I am doing the 1 min interval, I want to change the time to 9:00:00 instead.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SAS stores time as the number of seconds. Since you want to round to the nearest minute or 5 minute, a translation would be, 5*60 = 300 & 60 seconds. The SAS round function supports this.

```
time_nearest_minute = round(time, 60);
time_nearest_minute5 = round(time, 300);
```

Edit based on comment:

```
Time_nearest_second5 = round(time, 5);
```

Comment: The question was not about 5 minutes but 5 seconds. It should be `time_nearest_5seconds = round(time, 5);`

Comment: Thanks Dirk, I've edited the post to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 1):

### For the processing by minute, you can use

```
data _quotes_interval / view = _quotes_interval; 
  set _quotes_processed;
  interval = intnx('MINUTE', time, 0, 'begin');
run;
```

`intnx` is by default used to add or substract time intervals. Here I add `0` binutes, but that is just because I need the function for its fourth parameter, which specifies to go back to the `'begin'` of the interval of 1 minute.

PS: For preformance reasons, I would use the `view=` option, to create a view on the existing data instead of copying all data.

### For processing by 5 second intervals

try `interval = intnx('SECOND5', time, 0, 'begin');`

### Disclaimer:

I do not have SAS on this computer. If it does not work, react in a comment and I will test it at work.

Comment: If so inclined, you could sign up for an online SAS account, via SAS Academics on Demand, Independent Learner track. No installation required and no maintenance, log in when you want/need.